# Regular elements of a module is open and dense

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be an algebraic Lie algebra and $V$ be a $\mathfrak{g}$-module, then for each $v\in V$, define $\mathfrak{g}^v = \{x\in\mathfrak{g}:xv = 0\}$. Let $V_{reg}$ be the set of all $v$ such that $\mathfrak{g}^v$ has minimal dimension.

I was reading a paragraph and it claims that $V_{reg}$ is open dense in $V$ (in the Zariski topology). So I need to show that the complement of $V_{reg}$ is an algebraic set, but I'm not sure how to see this, please help.

Comment: If you think about the representation $\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak{gl}_V$ you have a matrix with polynomial entries and you're looking for conditions that ensure the rref of that matrix doesn't have the maximal number of leading $1$'s.  This will of course be given by the vanishing of entries that would otherwise be non-zero and become a leading $1$.

Comment: But there *must* be a better way to make that rigorous.